# How to share my localhost mongodb database (for my MERN app)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

For the last 1-2 months I have been building a web app using MERN stack. I am new to web development, but my setup so far is:

**Mongo** - I have this only locally on my computer.

**Node API** - When I run my app locally, my node API is served on port 3001.

**React** - When I run my app locally, my frontend is served on port 3000.

I open up 3 different terminal windows, and run (a) mongod, (b) node index.js, and (c) npm start, to get the database / api / frontend running.

**How to Share** - I recently pushed my Node API and React Frontend code to github, for a developer friend of mine to fork the repo and help take a look at my code. However, even with the Node API and Front-end code, my friend will not be able to run my app because I my mongodb collections / my db are only local on my computer. How do I share this with him?

Thanks!

Comment: Too broad. The path of least resistance of course is to simply externally host the MongoDB instance. But even asking how to set up neworking configuration for sharing something on your own computer is probably again too broad and also off topic. You could ask networking questions on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/) but they will probably consider it broad as well, and as stated already in the "real world" you "share" things from an external shared resource. Find a hosting provider and give access to other project participants.

Comment: perfect this is exactly what i needed thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could dump the data to a file and commit it to an repository in regular basys, an example taken from [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/):

```
mongodump --host mongodb1.example.net --port 3017 --username user --password "pass" --out /opt/backup/mongodump-2013-10-24
```